# Maximum angle change within a ball

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, multivariable-calculus

Consider a vector $\mathbf{x}$ in $\Bbb R^{n}$ with a known norm ($\| \mathbf{x}\|=M)$, and conceptually $M$ is large.
Denote by $B_\epsilon(\mathbf{x})$ a ball with radius $\epsilon$ centered at $\mathbf{x}$.

I have two (related) questions:

i.

How to prove that vectors in $B_\epsilon(\mathbf{x})$ that maximize the angle between them and $\mathbf{x}$ are of the form :
\begin{align} 
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{x} + \epsilon\mathbf{v}
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{v}$ is a unit vector that is orthogonal to $\mathbf{x}$, and only this kind of vectors maximize the angle.

ii.

Write an expression that bounds the angle change within the ball as a function of $M$ and $\epsilon$.

My thoughts:

Intuitively I would expect that the angle change as a function of $M$ and $\epsilon$ would be inversely proportional to $M$ and proportional to $\epsilon$.
The angle is defined as:
\begin{align} 
\theta = \arccos \frac{\mathbf x \cdot \mathbf y}{\left\| \mathbf x \right\| \, \left\| \mathbf y \right\|}
\end{align}

So I would try to maximize this term, by using the first part of my question.

I am not sure how to proceed, and would appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance!

Edit :
Clearly my guess was wrong. I'm looking for algebraic proof for $\mathbf{y}$ form.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is incorrect. If you want to maximize the angle, you want $y$ to be tangent to the boundary of the $\epsilon$-ball, similar to this picture:

[image]

The maximum angle is thus $$\arcsin \frac{\epsilon}{M}.$$ You can use this to give an expression for what $y$ can be.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Is there an Algebraic proof for this phenomenon using the definition of the angle with scalar product?

Answer (score 0):

In the answer by @angryavian, the angle being maximised is $\angle PAO$, but the question asks to maximize the angle between **x** (line AO) and a vector in the sphere (e.g. line OP and OQ). The 'maximum' is deemed to be orthogonal in the context of the question, I think, with any value larger than 90 degrees being interpreted as closer to **x** in the other direction.